# Cannot assign to read only property 'leaveDays' of object '[object Object]'

Tags: typescript

```
export interface Vacation {
 leaveId: number | null;
 employeeId: number | null;
 employeeName: string;
 employeeLogin: string;
 leaveTypeId: number | null;
 startDate: Date | string;
 endDate: Date | string;
 leaveDays: Array<LeaveDays>;

}

export interface LeaveDays {
 year: number;
 days: number;
}


 arrlistYears.forEach(element => {
  const arrListCurrentYears: Vacation[] = vacations.filter(item => item.years == element)
    .sort((a, b) => new Date(b.startDate as string).getTime() - new Date(a.startDate as string).getTime());

  const test: Vacation[] = [...arrListCurrentYears];
  test.map(value => value.leaveDays = value.leaveDays.filter(leaveDays => leaveDays.year == 2023));
```

I have problem with this:

> Cannot assign to read only property 'leaveDays' of object '[object Object]'

I think that I work on a copy of the array but I always get the error. Need help with code, where I have a problem with map() and update. leaveDays ?

```
[
  {
   "leaveId": 63915,
   "leaveTypeName": null,
   "employeeId": null,
   "employeeName": null,
   "employeeLogin": null,
   "leaveTypeId": 1,
   "startDate": "2019-12-30",
   "endDate": "2020-01-02",
   "leaveDays": [
     {
      "year": 2019,
      "days": 2
     },
     {
      "year": 2020,
      "days": 2
     }
   ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please upload test/mock data for `arrListYears` and `vacations`.

Comment: I have given above data in json

Comment: the above data should be the vacations object but what is `arrListYears`? it is not possible to know what is wrong with the code above without having all the input data

Comment: const arrlistYears: Array<number> = vacations.map(item => item.years).filter((vacations, index, self) => self.indexOf(vacations) === index),  it's array with segregation vacations by year and i need update object leaveDays in each list item arrListCurrentYears.

Comment: `vacations.filter(item => item.years == element)` There is no `years` property defined in the interface `Vacations`. The json data you provided does not match the iteration and properties your trying to access.